# HTML form not hitting the Servlet file || HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: html, eclipse, servlets, jdbc

I am making a project(In Eclipse IDE) which operates basic operations of **Inventory** Management like **Add Product**, **Delete Product**, **Sell Product**, **Purchase Product**, **Fetch Product Details**.

Project Overview:
Project Name: **StoreInventory**
Files:
*1. StoreInventory.java
2. StoreInventoryDAO.java
3. StoreInventoryServlet.java
4. index.html
5. index.css
6. error.html*

**StoreInventoryDAO.java** below

```
package storeInventoryDAO;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import storeInventoryModel.StoreInventory;

public class StoreInventoryDAO {

    private String jdbcURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/storeInventoryDB?useSSL=false";
    private String jdbcUserName="root";
    private String jdbcPassword="Jitu@1998";
    
    private final String queryAddProduct="INSERT into Products (name,id,unit,quantity,amountPerQuantity,minimumQuantityAlert) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    private final String queryGetDeletionInfo="SELECT name,unit,quantity,amountPerQuantity from Products where id=?";
    private final String queryDeleteProduct="DELETE from Products where id=?";
    private final String queryGetSellingInfo="SELECT name,unit,quantity,amountPerQuantity from Products where id=?";
    private final String querySellProduct="UPDATE Products SET quantity=?";
    private final String queryGetPurchasingInfo="SELECT name,unit,quantity,amountPerQuantity from Products where id=?";
    private final String queryPurchaseProduct="UPDATE Products SET quantity=?";
    private final String queryFetchProductDetails="SELECT name,unit,quantity,amountPerQuantity,minimumQuantityAlert from Products where id=?";
    private final String queryListAllProducts="SELECT id,name from Products";
    
    //Common function to establish a connection
    protected Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,jdbcUserName,jdbcPassword);
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
    
    //Add Product
    public void addProduct(StoreInventory newProduct) {
        try(Connection connection=getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(queryAddProduct)){
            preparedStatement.setString(1, newProduct.getName());
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, newProduct.getId());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, newProduct.getUnit());
            preparedStatement.setInt(4, newProduct.getQuantity());
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, newProduct.getAmountPerQuantity());
            preparedStatement.setInt(6, newProduct.getMinimumQuantityAlert());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
    
    //Get Deletion Info
    public StoreInventory getDeletionInfo(int id) {
        StoreInventory deletionInfo=null;
        try(Connection connection=getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(queryGetDeletionInfo)){
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                String name=rs.getString("name");
                String quantityUnit=rs.getInt("quantity")+" "+rs.getString("unit");
                int totalAmount=rs.getInt("quantity")*rs.getInt("amountPerQuantity");
                deletionInfo=new StoreInventory(id,name,quantityUnit,totalAmount);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return deletionInfo;
    }
    
    //Delete Product
    public void deleteProduct(int id) {
        try(Connection connection=getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(queryDeleteProduct)){
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    //Get Selling Info
    public StoreInventory getSellingInfo(int id) {
        StoreInventory sellingInfo=null;
        try(Connection connection=getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(queryGetSellingInfo)){
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                String name=rs.getString("name");
                String unit=rs.getString("unit");
                //int quantity=rs.getInt("quantity");
                //int amountPerQuantity=rs.getInt("amountPerQuantity");
                sellingInfo=new StoreInventory(id,name,unit);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return sellingInfo;
    }
    
    //Sell Product
    public void sellProduct(StoreInventory sellingInfo,int sellingQuantity) {
        try(Connection connection=getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(querySellProduct)){
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, sellingQuantity-sellingInfo.getQuantity());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    
    //Get Purchasing Info
    public StoreInventory getPurchasingInfo(int id) {
        StoreInventory purchasingInfo=null;
        try(Connection connection=getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(queryGetPurchasingInfo)){
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                String name=rs.getString("name");
                String unit=rs.getString("unit");
                //int quantity=rs.getInt("quantity");
                //int amountPerQuantity=rs.getInt("amountPerQuantity");
                purchasingInfo=new StoreInventory(id,name,unit);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return purchasingInfo;
    }
    
    //Purchase Product
    public void purchaseProduct(StoreInventory purchasingProduct,int purchasingQuantity) {
        try(Connection connection=getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(queryPurchaseProduct)){
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, purchasingQuantity+purchasingProduct.getQuantity());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    
    //Fetch Product Details
    public StoreInventory fetchProductDetails(int id) {
        StoreInventory productInfo=null;
        try(Connection connection=getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(queryFetchProductDetails)){
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                String name=rs.getString("name");
                String quantityUnit=rs.getInt("quantity")+" "+rs.getString("unit");
                int totalAmount=rs.getInt("amountPerQuantity")*rs.getInt("amountPerQuantity");
                int amountPerQuantity=rs.getInt("amountPerQuantity");
                int minimumQuantityAlert=rs.getInt("minimumQuantityAlert");
                productInfo=new StoreInventory(id,name,quantityUnit,totalAmount,amountPerQuantity,minimumQuantityAlert);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return productInfo;
    }
    
    //List All Products
    public StoreInventory listAllProducts() {
        StoreInventory productsList=null;
        try(Connection connection=getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(queryListAllProducts)){
            //preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                
            while(rs.next()) {
                int id=rs.getInt("id");
                String name=rs.getString("name");
                productsList=new StoreInventory(id,name);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return productsList;
    }
}
```

**StoreInventoryServlet.java** below

```
package storeInventoryWeb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import storeInventoryDAO.StoreInventoryDAO;
import storeInventoryModel.StoreInventory;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class StoreInventoryServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/StoreInventory")
public class StoreInventoryServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private StoreInventoryDAO storeInventoryDAO;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public StoreInventoryServlet() {
        this.storeInventoryDAO=new StoreInventoryDAO();
    }
    
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.doGet(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action=request.getServletPath();
        switch(action) {
        case "/addProduct":
            addProduct(request,response);
            break;
        case "/getDeletionInfo":
            try {
                getDeletionInfo(request,response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case "/deleteProduct":
            deleteProduct(request,response);
            break;
        case "/getSellingInfo":
            try {
                getSellingInfo(request,response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case "/sellProduct":
            try {
                sellProduct(request,response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case "/getPurchasingInfo":
            try {
                getPurchasingInfo(request,response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case "/purchaseProduct":
            try {
                purchaseProduct(request,response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case "/fetchProductDetails":
            try {
                fetchProductDetails(request,response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:
            try {
                listAllProducts(request,response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    
    //Accept data from web,pass it to StoreInventory constructor,call DAO method
    private void addProduct(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        String unit=request.getParameter("unit");
        int quantity=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity"));
        int amountPerQuantity=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("amountPerQuantity"));
        int minimumQuantityAlert=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("minimumQuantityAlert"));
        StoreInventory newProduct=new StoreInventory(name,id,unit,quantity,amountPerQuantity,minimumQuantityAlert);
        storeInventoryDAO.addProduct(newProduct);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }
    
    //Accept data from web,pass it to DAO method,receive returned object from DAO method,display data on web
    private void getDeletionInfo(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException,ServletException,IOException{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        StoreInventory deletionInfo=storeInventoryDAO.getDeletionInfo(id);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
        request.setAttribute("id", deletionInfo);
        request.setAttribute("name", deletionInfo);
        request.setAttribute("quantityUnit", deletionInfo);
        request.setAttribute("totalAmount", deletionInfo);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
    
    //Accepts data from web,call DAO method
    private void deleteProduct(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        storeInventoryDAO.deleteProduct(id);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }
    
    //Accept data from web,call DAO method,receive returned object from DAO method,display data on web
    private void getSellingInfo(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException,ServletException,IOException{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        StoreInventory sellingInfo=storeInventoryDAO.getSellingInfo(id);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
        request.setAttribute("id", sellingInfo);
        request.setAttribute("name", sellingInfo);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
    
    //Accept data from web,call DAO method,receive returned object from DAO method, call another DAO method
    private void sellProduct(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException,ServletException,IOException{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        int sellingQuantity=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sellingQuantity"));
        StoreInventory sellingInfo=storeInventoryDAO.getSellingInfo(id);
        storeInventoryDAO.sellProduct(sellingInfo, sellingQuantity);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }
    
    //Accept data from web,call DAO method,receive returned object from DAO method,display data on web
    private void getPurchasingInfo(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException,ServletException,IOException{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        StoreInventory purchasingInfo=storeInventoryDAO.getPurchasingInfo(id);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
        request.setAttribute("id", purchasingInfo);
        request.setAttribute("name", purchasingInfo);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
    
    //Accept data from web,call DAO method,receive returned object from DAO method, call another DAO method
    private void purchaseProduct(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException,ServletException,IOException{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        int purchasingQuantity=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("purchasingQuantity"));
        StoreInventory purchasingInfo=storeInventoryDAO.getPurchasingInfo(id);
        storeInventoryDAO.purchaseProduct(purchasingInfo, purchasingQuantity);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }
    
    //Accept data from web,call DAO method,display data on web
    private void fetchProductDetails(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException,ServletException,IOException{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        StoreInventory productInfo=storeInventoryDAO.fetchProductDetails(id);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
        request.setAttribute("id", productInfo);
        request.setAttribute("name", productInfo);
        request.setAttribute("quantityUnit", productInfo);
        request.setAttribute("totalAmount", productInfo);
        request.setAttribute("amountPerQuantity", productInfo);
        request.setAttribute("minimumQuantityAlert", productInfo);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
    
    private void listAllProducts(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException,ServletException,IOException{
        StoreInventory productsList=storeInventoryDAO.listAllProducts();
        request.setAttribute("productsList", productsList);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

**index.html** below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<title>Store Inventory</title>
<head>

  <title>Store Inventory Management</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  
  <script>

    function addProduct() {
      var taskWindow=document.getElementById("taskWindow");
      var addProduct = document.getElementById("addProduct");
      taskWindow.style.display="none";
      addProduct.style.display = "block";
      addProduct.opacity = "opacity 2500ms ease-in-out";
    }

    function getDeletionInfo() {
      var taskWindow=document.getElementById("taskWindow");
      var getDeletionInfo = document.getElementById("getDeletionInfo");
      taskWindow.style.display="none";
      getDeletionInfo.style.display = "block";
      getDeletionInfo.opacity = "opacity 2500ms ease-in-out";
    }

    function deleteProduct() {
      var getDeletionInfo = document.getElementById("getDeletionInfo");
      var deleteProduct = document.getElementById("deleteProduct");
      getDeletionInfo.style.display="none";
      deleteProduct.style.display = "block";
      deleteProduct.opacity = "opacity 2500ms ease-in-out";
    }

    function getSellingInfo() {
      var taskWindow=document.getElementById("taskWindow");
      var getSellingInfo = document.getElementById("getSellingInfo");
      taskWindow.style.display="none";
      getSellingInfo.style.display = "block";
      getSellingInfo.opacity = "opacity 2500ms ease-in-out";
    }

    function sellProduct(){
      var getSellingInfo=document.getElementById("getSellingInfo");
      var sellProduct=document.getElementById("sellProduct");
      getSellingInfo.style.display="none";
      sellProduct.style.display="block";
      sellProduct.opacity="opacity 2500ms ease-in-out";
    }

    function getPurchasingInfo() {
      var taskWindow=document.getElementById("taskWindow");
      var getPurchasingInfo = document.getElementById("getPurchasingInfo");
      taskWindow.style.display="none";
      getPurchasingInfo.style.display = "block";
      getPurchasingInfo.opacity = "opacity 2500ms ease-in-out";
    }

    function purchaseProduct() {
      var getPurchasingInfo=document.getElementById("getPurchasingInfo");
      var purchaseProduct = document.getElementById("purchaseProduct");
      getPurchasingInfo.style.display="none";
      purchaseProduct.style.display = "block";
      purchaseProduct.opacity = "opacity 2500ms ease-in-out";
    }
    
    function requestProductDetails() {
      var taskWindow=document.getElementById("taskWindow");
      var requestProductDetails = document.getElementById("requestProductDetails");
      taskWindow.style.display="none";
      requestProductDetails.style.display = "block";
      requestProductDetails.opacity = "opacity 2500ms ease-in-out";
    }

    function fetchProductDetails() {
      var requestProductDetails=document.getElementById("requestProductDetails");
      var fetchProductDetails = document.getElementById("fetchProductDetails");
      requestProductDetails.style.display="none";
      fetchProductDetails.style.display = "block";
      fetchProductDetails.opacity = "opacity 2500ms ease-in-out";
    }
    
    function cancelOperation() {
      var addProduct = document.getElementById("addProduct");
      var getDeletionInfo=document.getElementById("getDeletionInfo");
      var deleteProduct = document.getElementById("deleteProduct");
      var getSellingInfo=document.getElementById("getSellingInfo");
      var sellProduct = document.getElementById("sellProduct");
      var getPurchasingInfo=document.getElementById("getPurchasingInfo");
      var purchaseProduct = document.getElementById("purchaseProduct");
      var requestProductDetails=document.getElementById("requestProductDetails");
      var fetchProductDetails = document.getElementById("fetchProductDetails");
      addProduct.style.display = "none";
      getDeletionInfo.style.display="none";
      deleteProduct.style.display = "none";
      getSellingInfo.style.display="none";
      sellProduct.style.display = "none";
      getPurchasingInfo.style.display="none";
      purchaseProduct.style.display = "none";
      requestProductDetails.style.display="none";
      fetchProductDetails.style.display = "none";
    }

  </script>
  
</head>

<body>

  <!-- operationButton-->
  <div id="taskWindow">
    <button class="operationButton" onclick="addProduct()"><b>Add Product</b></button>
    <button class="operationButton" onclick="getDeletionInfo()"><b>Delete Product</b></button>
    <button class="operationButton" onclick="getSellingInfo()"><b>Sell Product</b></button>
    <button class="operationButton" onclick="getPurchasingInfo()"><b>Purchase Product</b></button>
    <button class="operationButton" onclick="requestProductDetails()"><b>Fetch Product Details</b></button>
  </div>

  <!-- addProduct Operation -->
  <div class="operationPanel" id="StoreInventoryServlet/addProduct">
    <form action="addProduct" method="post">
      <div>
        <h1 class="operationHeading">Add Product</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Name</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name...">
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Product ID</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID...">
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Unit</i>
        <select class="inputField" name="unit">
          <option>kg.</option>
          <option>gm.</option>
          <option>lt.</option>
          <option>ml.</option>
          <option>Dozen</option>
          <option>Piece</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Quantity</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity...">
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Price/Quantity</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="amountPerQuantity" placeholder="Enter Price/Quantity...">
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Minimum Quantity Alert</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="minimumQuantityAlert" placeholder="Enter Minimum Quantity Alert...">
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="cancelButton" onclick="cancelOperation()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- deleteProduct Operation -->
  <div class="operationPanel" id="getDeletionInfo">
    <form>
      <div>
        <h1 class="operationHeading">Delete Product</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">ID</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID...">
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="cancelButton" onclick="cancelOperation()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="submitButton" onclick="deleteProduct()">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="operationPanel" id="deleteProduct">
    <form>
      <div>
        <h1 class="operationHeading">Delete Product</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">ID</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="id" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Name</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="name" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Quantity</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="quantityUnit" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Total Amount</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="totalAmount" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="cancelButton" onclick="cancelOperation()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- sellProduct Operation -->
  <div class="operationPanel" id="getSellingInfo">
    <form>
      <div>
        <h1 class="operationHeading">Sell Product</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">ID</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID...">
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="cancelButton" onclick="cancelOperation()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="submitButton" onclick="sellProduct()">Sell</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="operationPanel" id="sellProduct">
    <form>
      <div>
        <h1 class="operationHeading">Sell Product</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">ID</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="id" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Name</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="name" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Quantity</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="sellingQuantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity...">
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="cancelButton" onclick="cancelOperation()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">Sell</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- purchaseProduct Operation -->
  <div class="operationPanel" id="getPurchasingInfo">
    <form>
      <div>
        <h1 class="operationHeading">Purchase Product</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">ID</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID...">
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="cancelButton" onclick="cancelOperation()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="submitButton" onclick="purchaseProduct()">Purchase</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="operationPanel" id="purchaseProduct">
    <form>
      <div>
        <h1 class="operationHeading">Purchase Product</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">ID</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="id" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Name</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="name" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Quantity</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="purchasingQuantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity...">
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="cancelButton" onclick="cancelOperation()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">Purchase</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- fetchProductDetails Operation -->
  <div class="operationPanel" id="requestProductDetails">
    <form>
      <div>
        <h1 class="operationHeading">Fetch Product Details</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">ID</i>
        <input class="inputField" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID...">
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="cancelButton" onclick="cancelOperation()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="submitButton" onclick="fetchProductDetails()">Fetch</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="operationPanel" id="fetchProductDetails">
    <form>
      <div>
        <h1 class="operationHeading">Fetch Product Details</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">ID</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="id" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Name</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="name" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Total Quantity</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="quantityUnit" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Total Amount</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="totalAmount" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Amount Per Quantity</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="amountPerQuantity" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="formElement">
        <i class="label">Minimum Quantity Alert</i>
        <input class="automatedField" type="text" name="minimumQuantityAlert" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button class="cancelButton" onclick="cancelOperation()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer Coding -->
  <div id="Footer">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**database file code** below

```
create database storeInventoryDB;

use storeInventoryDB;

create table Products(
name varchar(30),
id int,
unit varchar(20),
quantity int,
amountPerQuantity int,
minimumQuantityAlert int);

DESC Products;
SELECT * from Products;
```

**Project Hierarchy**

**Problem**:- **HTTP Status 404 - Not Found**

I tried multiple solutions like putting/removing "/" in @WebServlet in **Servlet** file, making changes in action attribute of Add Product Form in *html* file. But none of these solved the issue.
**Must Read**:- Whosoever is trying to help me,when you go through the HTML file, i would advice you to focus on just Add Product section of HTML because rest of the forms are little complicated to understand in terms of connectivity with Servlet. And i am damn sure of the entire source code of all the files being correct. Only problem which exits is either in the action attribute of HTML or in the Servlet.

Someone help me out **PLEASE**.